# Prevent width changes applying position:fixed

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, css-tables, fixed-header-tables

It was hard to exhaustively describe my question in the title so I'll try to be clearer in the description.
I build a table using `<div>` and applying the CSS properties `display: table` etc. avoiding the semantic `<table>` approach purposely.
All is working fine and now I'm trying to achieve a fixed header using `position: fixed`. The result is:

[image]

Obliviously the `display: table-cell` applied to the rest of the cell is provoking this not desiderated behavior. The cells are auto-resizing adapting to the new content and following just the `min-width: 100px` rule I applied in the CSS file.

Here a link to a working pen: https://codepen.io/l_core/pen/ZLQEjq

Is there a way to achieve a perfect align between the header and the "body" cells with a pure CSS approach? I could try to re-calculate width with JS but I'm sure that there is an elegant way to achieve this and I'd like to ask the experts here how to do this.

Below the code:

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Row Container -->
    <div class="row-container" id="row1">

      <!-- Header cell container -->
      <div class="cell cell-header" id="cell1">

        <!-- Cell content container -->
        <div class="cell-content">
          <span>Cell</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cell cell-header" id="cell2">
        <div class="cell-content">
          <span>Cell</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cell cell-header" id="cell3">
        <div class="cell-content">
          <span>Cell</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cell cell-header" id="cell4">
        <div class="cell-content">
          <span>Cell</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cell cell-header" id="cell5">
        <div class="cell-content">
          <span>Cell</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#row1 {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Please take a look to the pen I posted above for the full code. I'm not sure what it is a good idea to post it in his whole length.

Comment: Why are you not using `<table>` HTML. This is what its for.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your answer. I'm avoiding the semantic `<table>` approach purposely. Take it as a "personal project"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed element is out of the normal html flow. So, your table header is not part of the table anymore.
So, they behave independently.

You could set a constant (or dynamically calculated using JS) width for all cells instead of min-width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to avoid a constant width set up by a CSS rule. When you talk about "dynamically calculated" you are referring to a JS implementation?

Comment: Yes. You would need to get the width of your cells to determine the maximum width.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if You use Flex as a main Container.
It will solve your issue of width.

1. Make the Main Container as flex container.
2. Inside Main-Container, make flex-direction as "column".

And more on Flex, you can search:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek for your answer! I currently solved using a custom JS code which is setting the width of the cells. But I'll soon try your solution to see if it is working!

Comment: I tried creating a fixed-position element inside flex container with "column" direction. And it didn't solve the width problem. 

Can you please provide a clear example? thanks